# Launch other activity after createChooser

Tags: android

How can you redirect to another activity once the application that was launched by createChooser such as show below is complete?

My attempt below ends up with the second intent being triggered before the createChooser launches. I noticed that when I press the back button on the newly launched activity is when the createChooser appears on the activity I wanted to launch it from.

I also tried to wrap the createChooser in startActivityForResult and then launch the second intent using onActivityResult but the result was the same

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
Intent trackIntent = new Intent(InformContacts.this, TrackOffers.class);
startActivity(trackIntent);
```

Here's the entire code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class InformContacts extends Activity {

private static String ITEM_NAME = "Item name";
private static String ITEM_PRICE = "Item price";
private static String ITEM_PIC_URI = "Item pic uri";
public static final int REQUEST_SEND_EMAIL = 0;

ArrayList<Contact> listContacts;
ListView lvContacts;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inform_contacts);

    listContacts = new ContactFetcher(this).fetchAll();
    lvContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContacts);
    final ContactsAdapter adapterContacts = new ContactsAdapter(this, listContacts);
    lvContacts.setAdapter(adapterContacts);

    final Button informButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);

    final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    final String uriSharedPref = preferences.getString(ITEM_PIC_URI, "item pic uri");

    informButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ArrayList emailsList = adapterContacts.emailsSelected;
            String item = preferences.getString(ITEM_NAME, "item name");
            Float price = preferences.getFloat(ITEM_PRICE,0);

            //May use the uriSharedPref string to embed actual url in email and show recipients like I did with publishing house
            String sellingMessage = "Hello,\n\nI'm selling my "+ item +" for KES "+price+".\n\nGet back to me if you're interested in buying.\n\n" + uriSharedPref;
            String subject = "Selling my "+item;

            sendEmail(emailsList, sellingMessage, subject);

            //Intent trackIntent = new Intent(InformContacts.this, TrackOffers.class);
            //startActivity(trackIntent);
        }
    });
}

protected void sendEmail(ArrayList<String> arrayOfEmails, String message, String subject) {

    Log.i("Send email", "");
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    //First Step: convert ArrayList to an Object array
    Object[] objEmails = arrayOfEmails.toArray();
    //Second Step: convert Object array to String array
    String[] strEmails = Arrays.copyOf(objEmails, objEmails.length, String[].class);

    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, strEmails);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

    if(isIntentSafe){

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."), REQUEST_SEND_EMAIL);
        //finish();
        Log.i("Done sending email...", "");
    }
    else{

        Toast.makeText(InformContacts.this, "No email app found. Email won't be sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_SEND_EMAIL){

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrackOffers.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Surely it will work in the startActivityResult if u call next activity().Share you code

Comment: Hello @R2R, I've updated my question with the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

Change to:

```
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_SEND_EMAIL){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrackOffers.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Instead of:

```
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_SEND_EMAIL){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TrackOffers.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks R2R. That worked. Happy New Year by the way  What made yours work?